# Propagate unchecked exception in Jetty handler to main thread

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to throw an runtime exception in my Jetty handler. However, it seems that Jetty swallow the exception and continue to listen to new request. I understand that it is a desirable behavior for most people as we don't want the server to die from an unchecked exception.

Though, I am still wondering I can somehow tell Jetty to propagate upward to the main thread?

The example I have is as follow:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class HelloWorld extends AbstractHandler
{
    public void handle(String target,
                       Request baseRequest,
                       HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
        throw new RuntimeException("testing");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(new HelloWorld());
        server.start();
        server.join();

    }
}
```

Derek